# React Native - React Navigation Deep Link Does not work on Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

currently i'm working on React Native Android Project, I want to use deep link on some page.
But somehow the link always redirect to login page instead of signup page.

already tried `adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "myapp://mobile/signup"`

i am afraid incorrect in nested navigation.

or should I put **path** on all screen?  because i dont put it all

**"react-navigation": "^3.11.1"
"react-native": "0.60.4"**

router.js

```
const prefix = 'myapp://'
<Navigation ref={(comp) => (this.navigator = comp)} uriPrefix={prefix} />
```

navigation/index.js

```
const LoginStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
      LoginScreen: { screen: LoginScreen },
      SignUpScreen: { 
        screen: SignUpScreen,
        path: 'signup',
       },
      ForgotPasswordScreen: { screen: ForgotPasswordScreen },
    },
    {
      navigationOptions: { tabBarVisible: false },
    },
    {
      mode: "modal",
      header: null,
      transitionConfig: () => TransitionConfig,
    }
);

const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
      Default: {
        screen: HomeStack,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <TabBarIcon icon={Images.Icon} tintColor={tintColor} />
          ),
        },
      },
      LoginStack: { 
        screen: LoginStack,
        path: 'login', 
      },
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Default',
      tabBarComponent: TabBar,
      tabBarPosition: "bottom",
      swipeEnabled: false,
      animationEnabled: false,
      tabBarOptions: {
        showIcon: true,
        showLabel: true,
        activeTintColor: Color.tabbarTint,
        inactiveTintColor: Color.tabbarColor,
      },
      lazy: true,
      navigationOptions: {
        gestureDirection: I18nManager.isRTL ? "inverted" : "default",
      },
    }
);

const AuthNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    LoginScreen: { screen: LoginScreen },
    SignUpScreen: { 
      screen: SignUpScreen,
      path: 'signup', 
    },
  },
  {
    mode: "modal",
    header: null,
    transitionConfig: () => TransitionConfig,
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(
  Config.Login.RequiredLogin
    ? createSwitchNavigator(
        {
          AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
          App: AppNavigator,
          Auth: AuthNavigator,
        },
        {
          initialRouteName: "AuthLoading",
        }
      )
    : AppNavigator
);
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="mobile" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with react-navigation 4.x. so I ended up first navigate to screen that I wanted to open in deep linking then open url. In your case if you want to go to specific url page in login and after some process navigate to sign up, you should first navigate to SignUp then go to url. The code bellow shows my button which open url

```
const goToWebPage = () => {
    props.navigation.navigate('SignUp');
    Linking.canOpenURL(`${paymentUrl}\/${id}`).then(supported => {
        if (supported) {
           Linking.openURL(`${paymentUrl}\/${id}`);
        } 
    });
 }
```

the main problem I think is in createSwitchNavigator.
before using my approch, use https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e approch and disable deep linking by adding `enableURLHandling={false}` to Navigator and remove `uriPrefix={prefix}` so if it wont work, use my approch.